# Why is grep giving unexpected result?

Tags: linux, grep

I have files with extension .m and .slx. I want to use grep to check modified m-files from svn log: using

```
svn status | grep "M  " | grep ".m"
```

I get

```
M       foo.m
M       model1.slx.
```

I would expect to see foo.m only. But why do I see model1.slx too? It should be filtered out by the second grep.

Comment: `grep` uses regular expressions. `.m` means "any character (`.`) followed by `m`". The second line matches this description; it contains a space (or a tab) before `m`odel1.slx. You have to anchor `.m` to the end of the line: `\.m$`. Use `man -s 7 regex` to learn about regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing is because the `.` is meta-character in regular expression context which needs to be escaped to deprive of its special meaning (to match any character).

Your requirement is not clear if you want to list files ending with `.m` and `.slx` only or files starting with `M` and ending with `.m`. For the former use the suggestion below and for the latter do `grep ^M.*\.m$`

You could just use one `grep` over this by enabling the `-E` extended regular expressions support mode

```
svn status | grep -E '(\.m|\.slx)$'
```

The alternation `|` operator is enabled by default on ERE mode but needs to be escaped when using the BRE (Basic Regular expressions) mode

```
svn status | grep '\.m$\|\.slx$'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.` matches *any* character.  Per [the POSIX regex rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) for the `.` character:

> Matches any single character (many applications exclude newlines, and exactly which characters are considered newlines is flavor-, character-encoding-, and platform-specific, but it is safe to assume that the line feed character is included). Within POSIX bracket expressions, the dot character matches a literal dot. For example, a.c matches "abc", etc., but [a.c] matches only "a", ".", or "c".

To match a `.` character not in `[]` brackets, you need to escape it with a `\` character:

```
\.m
```

will match the literal `.m`.

Answer (score 0):

*I want to use grep to check modified m-files from svn logs:*

```
$ svn status | grep ^M.*\.m$
M       foo.m
```

ie. line starts with an `M` and ends with `.m`.